# Unity (C#) - Canvas Scaler resizes Canvas but grid layout elements inside don't

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

OK so the title is a bit hard to understand so let me explain.

I have an inventory canvas, and inside there is an inventory panel. Inside that there is a slot panel, which has a grid layout group attached so the slots are spaced nicely. When the game starts the slot panel gets populated with slots. If the user picks up an item, the slot will be filled with an item. Slot and Item are prefabs.

I want the inventory to scale with screen size, so I changed the Canvas Scaler and set it to scale with screen size, set a reference resolution to 1280x720 (because that fit quite nicely at the size I already had) and set match width or height.

Here are some images of the results:

At the reference resolution (1280x720):

[image: At 1280x720]

This looks nice and is exactly what it should be.

At a smaller size than reference (800x600):

[image: At 800x600]

At a larger size than reference (1600x900):

[image: At 1600x900]

How do I allow the grid layout group to keep a consistent spacing but resize the slots accordingly so that changing the resolution will keep everything at a set percentage of the screen space.

Thanks!

Comment: Anyone? Im really stuck on this

Comment: you can add an `Aspect Ratio Fitter` to the desired `GameObject`, that way it will remain a certain ratio, relative to the canvas, doc's [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AspectRatioFitter.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Hristo said in comments section,

Add [Aspect Ratio Fitter](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AspectRatioFitter.html) component to your first level children of `canvas` object. And it will solve the problem.